# Filling in the list of the required format in the python loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create a list structure in a loop:

```
[children:[{text: "Title 1", id: '1', expanded: true,children: [{text: "title2", leaf: true ,},{text: "title3", leaf: true}]},{text: "Title4", id: '4', expanded: true, children: [{text: "title5", leaf: true,} ]}]]
```

The source data looks like this:

```
mylist =[{'id': '1', 'name': 'Title1', 'id_parent': '0'}, {'id': '2', 'name': 'title2', 'id_parent': '1'}, {'id': '3', 'name': 'title3', 'id_parent': '1'}, {'id': '4', 'name': 'Title4', 'id_parent': '0'}, {'id': '5', 'name': 'title5', 'id_parent': '4'}]
```

Using recursion, I go through the data and get parental and childish records:

```
def get_parent(id_parent):
    c = []
    for x in mylist:
        if not x["id"] == id_parent and x["id_parent"] == id_parent:
            if x["id_parent"] == id_parent:
                x['expanded'] = True
            else:
                x['leaf'] = True
            c.append(x)
    return(c)
def get_tree(t):
    lst = []
    main_data = []
    for x in get_parent(t):
        all_stor = {}
        all_stor["text"] = x['name']
        all_stor["id"] = x['id']
        if x.get('expanded'):
            all_stor["expanded"] = x['expanded']
        else:
            all_stor["leaf"] = x['leaf']

        main_data.append(all_stor)
        lst.append([main_data, get_tree(x["id"])])
    return lst
main = get_tree("0")
print(main)
```

How to fill the main_data list in a loop in order to get the necessary structure?

Comment: What you are trying to create is not a valid Python data structure.

Comment: Are you trying to create a dict or a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expected output should be a list of children from the root level:

```
def get_tree(l, parent='0'):
    children = []
    for d in l:
        if d['id_parent'] == parent:
            details = {'text': d['name'], 'id': d['id']}
            grand_children = get_tree(l, d['id'])
            if grand_children:
                details.update({'expanded': True, 'children': grand_children})
            else:
                details['leaf'] = True
            children.append(details)
    return children
```

so that with your sample input, `get_tree(mylist)` would return:

`[{'text': 'Title1', 'id': '1', 'expanded': True, 'children': [{'text': 'title2', 'id': '2', 'leaf': True}, {'text': 'title3', 'id': '3', 'leaf': True}]}, {'text': 'Title4', 'id': '4', 'expanded': True, 'children': [{'text': 'title5', 'id': '5', 'leaf': True}]}`

Comment: Thank you. Your answer helped me a lot